# Google Apps Script UI: What to do if already logged into Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-for-education

I'm using Google Apps Script UI to create forms for students at my school.  I've restricted access to my domain for added security, and to capture users' email addresses.

The problem is that many of our students have separate Gmail accounts. If they are already logged into Gmail (not our domain), they don't get a log-in page, but something prompting them to request access.

Any suggestions for avoiding this?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I saw a request in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) for an account choosing feature, but my guess is that you'll want to allow anyone to access your web app and show a custom prompt if their email is non-domain.  I don't know how well this would work with shared computers, but creating separate Chrome user accounts for each of my Google accounts has solved all my multiple sign-in pain.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your answer.  The part in the middle: "allow anyone to access your web app and show a custom prompt if their email is non-domain" is exactly what I would like to happen. Currently I don't see that as an option for Google Docs forms or coded UI forms (published to the domain only).

Comment: What do you mean by "creating separate Chrome user accounts for each of my Google accounts"?

Comment: Why don't you publish to anyone instead of domain only?  Chrome > Settings > Add new user, is what I was referring that students do.

Comment: A few reasons. The main one is that forms are used by students to get their own information, so restricting them adds more security, and it can help us confirm their identity if there are any problems. In the future, I'd like to make the forms check their email against what we have in our records.

Comment: If you could capture the email address up front (`Session.getEffectiveUser()`) you could compare it to a whitelist or match it against a regular expression representing only your domain, then handle the result however you want. Except for redirects.

Comment: The problem is that we don't have their non-domain Gmail addresses. These are new students who are assigned domain addresses when they matriculate.